# Scanning from user input in a for loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to scan user input in a for loop except for the first iteration of the loop 2 pieces of data are required for it to continue to the next step and I don't understand why. I'll show my code below but as a heads up I'm really new to this and not very good, I'm not even sure if the method i'm using is the most efficient.

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <math.h>

#define     w   1.0
#define     R   1.0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int     tmp;
double  *x, *v, *m, *k;

x = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));
v = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));
m = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));
k = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));

if(x != NULL)
{
    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        sscanf(argv[tmp+1], "%lf", &x[tmp]);
    }
}
else
{
    printf("**************************\n");
    printf("**Error allocating array**\n");
    printf("**************************\n");
}

if(argc <= 2)
{
    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("**There must be at least 2 masses!**\n");
    printf("************************************\n");
}
else if(argc == 3)
{
    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the velocity of Block %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf\n", &v[tmp]);
    }

    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the mass of Block %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf\n", &m[tmp]);
    }

    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the spring constant of Spring %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf\n", &k[tmp]);
    }
}
else
{
    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the velocity of Mass %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf\n", &v[tmp]);
    }

    printf("Input a value for the mass of each Block\n");
    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {   
        scanf("%lf\n", &m[tmp]);
    }

    printf("Input a value for the spring constant of each Spring\n");
    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        scanf("%lf\n", &k[tmp]);
        printf("%lf\n", &k[tmp]);
    }
}   
}
```

So yes the main problem is when taking a value for the velocity of block 1 it requires two values

Comment: scanf("%lf%*c",&v[temp]); may solve the problem.

Comment: Yes you are correct, my bad I guess for not checking old posts thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the white-space `"\n"` after each format.

```
// scanf("%lf\n", &v[tmp]);
scanf("%lf", &v[tmp]);
```

---

The white-space `"\n"` after `"%lf"` directs `scanf()` to continue scanning and consuming white-space (e.g. `' '`, `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `'\r'` and typically 4 others) until a non-white-space `char` is found.  This will consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` *and* look for more white-space.

Since `stdin` is typically buffered, the entire next line needs to be entered, before the `scanf("\n")` sees any of it.

Once `scanf("\n")` encounters a non-white-space, it puts it back in to `stdin` for the *next* I/O operation.

---

`scanf()`, in general, presents challenges when errant input is entered.  For robust handling of evil user input, consider an `fgets()/sscanf()` combo.  (or `fgets()/strtod()`)

```
char buf[50];
double d;
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &d) != 1) Handle_ParseError();
// good to go
```

The following does consume the character after the `double`, which is typically the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but creates error handle challenges should input like "1.23.45" occurs.

```
// scanf("%lf\n", &m[tmp]);
scanf("%lf%*c", &m[tmp]);  // Not recommended.
```

Whatever code path taken, always a good idea to check the result of `scanf()/sscanf()/fcanf()`, especially when reading `double`.

---

The white-space directives `" "`, `"\n"`, `"\t"`, etc. all behave the same.  Any white-space directive in the format string consumes any white-space.

```
// All work the same.    
scanf("%lf\n", &v[tmp]);
scanf("%lf\t", &v[tmp]);
scanf("%lf ", &v[tmp]);
```